# Навигационое меню не на всю ширину

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

Хотел сделать навигационое меню снизу в итоге получилось так[image: Получилось так]
Потом решил взять еще какой нибудь код с интернета и получилось все так же

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: url('/img/bitva.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: rgb(119, 238, 21);
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.ferma {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.modpack {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.modpacks {
  width: 170px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper .left,
.wrapper .center,
.wrapper .right {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.modpack {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.modpacks {
  width: 170px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 20px;
}

.wrapper .item {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .item h3 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: aqua;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.menu ul {
  display: table-row;
}

.menu li {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #252b30;
}

.menu ul li:hover,
.menu a:hover {
  background: #666;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="img/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Логотип">
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="https://minecraft-inside.ru/mods/?ysclid=lrglyx5fm1690737887">МОДЫ</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://minecraft-inside.ru/modpacks/?ysclid=lrglz5tm6y628404644">МОДПАКИ</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://minecraftz.ru/24-luchshih-fermy-minecraft-iyul-2023/?ysclid=lrglzew4qv526681098">ФЕРМЫ</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://vk.com/killershademon">ЗА ПОМОЩЬЮ</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
<main>
  <section class="section-about-1">
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <nav></nav>
</footer>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/мобы.jpg" alt="Left image">
    <h3>Модифика́ция (англ. Modification, сокращённо мод (англ. Mod)) — это дополнение от сторонних разработчиков, которое изменяет или дополняет оригинальный контент Minecraft.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/модпаки.jpg" alt="Center image">
    <h3>Модифика́ция (англ. Modification, сокращённо мод (англ. Mod)) — это дополнение от сторонних разработчиков, которое изменяет или дополняет оригинальный контент Minecraft.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/ферма.jpg" alt="Right image">
    <h3>Модифика́ция (англ. Modification, сокращённо мод (англ. Mod)) — это дополнение от сторонних разработчиков, которое изменяет или дополняет оригинальный контент Minecraft.</h3>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="https://minecraft-inside.ru/mods/?ysclid=lrglyx5fm1690737887">ТЕХ.ПОДДЕРЖКА</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://minecraft-inside.ru/modpacks/?ysclid=lrglz5tm6y628404644">DISCORD</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://minecraftz.ru/24-luchshih-fermy-minecraft-iyul-2023/?ysclid=lrglzew4qv526681098">TELEGRAM</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://vk.com/killershademon">VK</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Не берите абы какой код с инета, пишите свой, осмысленный. И дополните ваш вопрос собственно вашими хотелками. Как у вас получилось понятно, а вы что хотели сделать? Как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: что б не было пустого места слева а было во всю ширину навигационное меню и свой код я пока что не смогу писать потому что я только 2 недели назад начал изучать ну я когда беру код я экспериментирую что как работает а самому не получится, одним словом хочу что б был во всю ширину так же как и справа

Comment: _Хотел сделать навигационое меню снизу в итоге получилось так_ => а как хотели ? (не очень понятно как хотели, потому что на скриншоте меню и есть "снизу") //добро пожаловать на сайт Артем, предлагаю, ознакомиться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я хочу что б в левой стороне навигационного меню (которе снизу) было так же как и справа (не было свободного места)
Справа нету пустого места и он занимает все место а слевой стороры навигационного меню (слева снизу)  есть не большой пропуск и он не полностью занимает

Comment: в класс для body добавьте `margin: 0`, это уберет отступы.

Comment: спасибо большое друг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально у всех элементов имеется `margin`, его надо обнулить

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```